# How to use CriteriaBuilder in JPA with SubQuery result?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have thinking about three entity relation.
The First User and UserBlock Entity.

They are connected by Constraint with UserId and also have blockedUserId, it's same another userId, And Posting and User Entity are connected by constraints.

So, Posting Entity has Owner, which calls user's another name

[User, UserBlock and Posting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3qaI.jpg)

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Cacheable(value = CacheValues.POSTING_TIMELINE, key = "{'find', #user ,#clazz.name, #sinceId, #maxId, #count}")
public List<PostingDto> findTimeline(User user, Class<? extends Posting> clazz, Long sinceId, Long maxId, int count) {

    /**
     * Below Original Source Code
     */
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<?> query = cb.createQuery(clazz);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    Root<? extends Posting> root = query.from(clazz);

    if(sinceId != null && !sinceId.equals(0L)) {
        predicates.add(cb.gt(root.get(Fields.ID), sinceId));
    }

    if(maxId != null && !maxId.equals(0L)) {
        predicates.add(cb.le(root.get(Fields.ID), maxId));
    }

    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})).orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(Fields.ID)));

    if(user.getId() == 1636891L) {
        log.info("PostingService.findTimelineToUserBlock userIdDto: " + findTimelineToUserBlock(user, clazz, sinceId, maxId, count));
    }
    return em.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(count).getResultList().stream().map(o -> PostingDto.of((Posting)o)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

and I want to remove subQuery result-set like this SQL.

Although try to do join method in JPA subQuery, I failed it, for User and Posting was connected but UserBlock and Posting not.

In searching, JPA CriteriaBuilder Join required to do relation between two entity. Although There are Join Constraints problem,  I have try to get SQL result and success below, but I don't implement this way for CriteriaBuilder.

**Join Query**

```
select * from posting p LEFT OUTER JOIN (select blocked_user_id from user_block where user_id = 1636891) ub on p.owner_id = ub.blocked_user_id where ub.blocked_user_id is null
```

**Not Join Query (with Sub Query)**

```
select * from posting where owner_id not in (select blocked_user_id from user_block where user_id = 1636891);
```

In result, I have try to do like below code with SubQuery but failed.

```
  /**
 * @param user
 * @param clazz
 * @param sinceId
 * @param maxId
 * @param count
 * @return
 *
 * cacheable key added
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Cacheable(value = CacheValues.POSTING_TIMELINE, key = "{'find', #user ,#clazz.name, #sinceId, #maxId, #count}")
public List<PostingDto> findTimeline(User user, Class<? extends Posting> clazz, Long sinceId, Long maxId, int count) {

    /**
     * Below Original Source Code
     */
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<?> query = cb.createQuery(clazz);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    Root<? extends Posting> root = query.from(clazz);

    log.info("PostingService.findTimeline.currentUserId : " + user.getId());
    //log.info("PostingService.findTimeline.ownerId " + root.get("owner"));

    
    log.debug("findTimeline userinfo : {}", user);

    Subquery<Number> sq = query.subquery(Number.class);
    Root<UserBlock> root2 = sq.from(UserBlock.class);
    Expression<Number> blockedUserId = root2.get("blockedUserId");

    sq.select(blockedUserId);

    List<Predicate> userBlockPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if(user.getId() != null && user.getId() > 0){
        userBlockPredicates.add(cb.equal(root2.get("user").get("id"), user.getId()));
        sq.where(userBlockPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
    }
    predicates.add(root.get("owner").get("id").in(sq).not());
    

    if(sinceId != null && !sinceId.equals(0L)) {
        predicates.add(cb.gt(root.get(Fields.ID), sinceId));
    }

    if(maxId != null && !maxId.equals(0L)) {
        predicates.add(cb.le(root.get(Fields.ID), maxId));
    }

    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})).orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(Fields.ID)));

    }
    return em.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(count).getResultList().stream().map(o -> PostingDto.of((Posting)o)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

if possible, want to do subQuery method type.
Please, somebody help me..

Comment: Atlast do u need to remove the subquery generated by Hibernate.. ?

Comment: @GnanaJeyam Yes right. I want to exclude SubQuery result. that's right

Comment: @GnanaJeyam One of users would block another user with userId, So I think it that one user have some of blocked user records.